# Add a delay to a button which is also playing a sound

Tags: audio, playback

I have a button link which I'm using the 'onClick' event to play a sound (the correct answer to a quiz question). I then want to add a delay so the sound has enough time to play out before the link function loads the next page in.
I've tried using the set time out function, but I can't get it to work. Is this the best way to do this?

```
HEAD
<script>
$("#correct").click(function()
{
var url = "question2.html";
//5000 is the number of milliseconds (or 5 seconds) that you want to wait before redirection.
var delay = 5000;
setTimeout(function() {
window.location.href = url;
}, delay);
});
</script>

BODY

<button onclick="document.getElementById('answer1').play()" id="correct">A) Reduce – make less waste in the first place</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using HTML5 tags. Therefore, it will only work with browser that support HTML5. However, I think is a bad idea to validate the answer via javascript, since people can cheat and look the code and know which answer is corrected.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- javascript/jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='audio'>This will be replaced with an audio tag</div>
  <button id="correct">A) Reduce – make less waste in the first place</button>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#correct").on('click',function (){
        $("#audio").stop("true").delay('5000').queue(function() {
            $(this).html('<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>');
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great, but I'd like the audio to play as soon at the button is clicked, then have link go to another html page once the audio has finished.